# PrestaShop 1.7 - search products by tag

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I noticed that in PrestaShop 1.7 you can tag products.
Is it possible to search for products by their tags programmatically?

So for example if I wanted to find products which contain any of the ['madcow, crazydog, happyant'] tags, how do I approach it?

```
$this->context->getProducts('tag', ['madcow, crazydog, happyant']) ?
```

or maybe

```
Product::getByAttribute('tag', ['madcow, crazydog, happyant'])
```

or similar?

any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the active products (id and name) foreach tag by doing:

```
$tag = new Tag(null, "tag", $idlang);
$products = $tag->getProducts();
```

The tag contructor also So your code could be something like:

```
$context = \Context::getContext();
$idlang = $context->language->id;

$tags = ['madcow', 'crazydog', 'happyant'];
$products = [];
foreach($tags as $t){
    $tag = new Tag(null, $t, $idlang);
    if($tag != null){
        $tag_products = $tag->getProducts();
        foreach($tag_products as $tg)
            $products[$tg['id_product']] = $tg['name'];
    }
}
```

EDIT: Taking account the comments, maybe it would be best to get all tags

```
$context = \Context::getContext();
$idlang = $context->language->id;

$tags = ['madcow', 'crazydog', 'happyant'];
$products = [];
foreach($tags as $t){
    $tag = new Tag(null, $t, $idlang);
    if($tag != null){
        $tag_products = $tag->getProducts();
        foreach($tag_products as $tg) {
            if(!isset($products[$tg['id_product']])) {
                 $products[$tg['id_product']] = [];
            }
            $products[$tg['id_product']][] = $tg['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you want to sort by number of tags found, you could do something like:

```
usort($product, function($a, $b) { return count($b) - count($a); });
```

Disclaimer: Not tested, please let me know if you find any mistake.

Comment: I hope @sadlyblue gets to see this question. I needed this code for my web, but I quite don't understand the last line, why would you want to overwrite the id_product with the name of the product?

Comment: @Germán I was using that array to get the id_product and tag name responsible for finding it. Of course, it woudn't work correctly if multiple tags "find" the same product, only the last one would returned.I'll try to edit the code to add the multiple tags, then you can even sort by relevance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet :

```
$array_tags = implode(',',['one','two','three']);

$id_lang = $this->context->language->id;

$products = Db::getInstance()->executeS('
    SELECT pl.id_product
    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl ON p.id_product = pl.id_product'.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').'
    '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
    WHERE pl.id_lang = '.(int) $id_lang.'
    AND product_shop.active = 1 
    AND p.id_product IN (SELECT pt.id_product FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_tag` pt WHERE pt.name IN ('.pSQL($array_tags).'))
    ORDER BY pl.name');
```